# get the data from TableView and insert into database

Tags: database, javafx, tableview, observablelist

In javafx I have created a some buttons and a `TableView` with some columns.
when I click the button, it adds the product into `TableView` columns.
so far, no problem with that.

I have created a `Product` class and using this I create a product object with `pID, pName, pQty, pPrice`.
example:

```
new Product(1, "Pen", 2, 3.50);
new Product(2, "notebook", 1, 5.00);
```

so whenever I click a product button it adds this product in next row.

Here is the problem I face:

I want to add all these rows in `TableView` to database I have created.

Is there a method to get all these objects one by one from `TableView` and insert it to database?

Or is there a method to populate database from `ObservableList`?

Comment: How about `tableView.getItems()`. It will return an ObservableList which u can iterate and post data one by one using JDBC.

Comment: Nope there is no method that does this for you for every type of connection to a database... It should be simple enough to insert a bunch of rows to a table though...

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution.
Actually I was so stupid as I was keep trying to insert all these data into another database and table with the same names.
So, basically no problem of inserting. sorry for the inconvenience. and Thanks for everyone who is interested.
Also, I am putting here the code I used for insertion. In case it could be useful for someone.

```
String query = "INSERT INTO Product (pID, pName, pQty, pPrice) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"; 
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);

            for(int i=0; i<data.size(); i++){

                 pst.setString(1, data.get(i).getRID().toString());
                 pst.setString(2, data.get(i).getRName());
                 pst.setString(3, data.get(i).getRQty().toString());
                 pst.setString(4, data.get(i).getRPrice().toString());


                 pst.execute();

            }
```

I have put this inside for loop, this way I was able to iterate each object member.